Java JDK and Gradle compatibility issue In Flutter Project

What went wrong:
Could not open cp_settings generic class cache for settings file 'D:\Programming\Flutter Projects\vagabondapp\android\settings.gradle' (C:\Users\rites.gradle\caches\7.5\scripts\5mlumqaneq7ne51ag5sa2).


BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit 'BuildScript' Unsupported class file major version 65

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 903ms
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                         1,625ms

┌─ Flutter Fix ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ [!] Your project's Gradle version is incompatible with the Java version that Flutter is using for Gradle.                                       │  
│                                                                                                                                                 │  
│ If you recently upgraded Android Studio, consult the migration guide at https://flutter.dev/to/to/java-gradle-incompatibility.                  │  
│                                                                                                                                                 │  
│ Otherwise, to fix this issue, first, check the Java version used by Flutter by running `flutter doctor --verbose`.                              │  
│                                                                                                                                                 │
│ Then, update the Gradle version specified in D:\Programming\Flutter Projects\vagabondapp\android\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties to be │  
│ compatible with that Java version. See the link below for more information on compatible Java/Gradle versions:                                  │  
│ https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html#java                                                                               │  
│                                                                                                                                                 │  
│                                                                                                                                                 │  
└─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘  
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1

now fix this
According to their Compatibility matrix for Java JDK 17 which I am using, the gradle version should be 7.3 on using 7.3 it's says use 8.0 or higher on using that version of gradle again it have the same error....
Please help me fix this
